# Unable to Use Nala Package Manager DietPi

Tags: python, dietpi

I have a fresh installation of DietPi on a RPi 3 Model B.

Also, I understand Nala package manager can provide better details about packages, optimize the mirrors, and even install multiple packages concurrently.

First, I tried installing Nala manually by adding new repo information with `echo "deb http://deb.volian.org/volian/ scar main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/volian-archive-scar-unstable.list; wget -qO - https://deb.volian.org/volian/scar.key | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/volian-archive-scar-unstable.gpg`

That led me down a rabbit hole of repeated repo files.

So, I flashed the SD card again and started from scratch.

Then, I installed Nala using pacstall which I understand is a collection of community repos per the official wiki on gitlab `pacstall -I nala-deb`

But when I run any Nala command, I get this module error:

"ImportError: cannot import name 'Group' from 'rich.console' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rich/console.py)"

I confirmed, and am running python version 3.9

Is DietPi too 'slim' to run big python apps perhaps?

Any advice would help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are downvoted, I wish people would at least type out their reason or not be allowed to downvote without explaining.

I recently found out about nala and use it on my Debian server. It is better in every way than apt as far as I have seen. It provides a mirror benchmark tool, allows multiple connections and gives more useful info. I am curious if you have gotten it running on dietpi, I just put it on my old raspi 3b+ and hope to use nala instead of apt....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130391)

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to solve this, and moved on with apt. I stopped tinkering with DietPi but would like to carve out time for it again. Thanks for your comment about the downvotes.

Comment: I got a downvote too lol. Obviously some gatekeeping going on here. Sorry I am not as smart as you guys. Stack exchange can be a great resource but I will just lurk and read from now on. It is set up in a way to not allow you to ask for info without making a new post where you get the "RTFM!!!" I read a ton and sometimes it is over my head.  This is a pretty niche thing and I also couldn't get it to work. I was just curious how it went for you so thanks for confirming for me. Back to reddit and forums for me. Lol

Comment: Sorry @Chenmunka, sincerely, I apologize for coming at you like that. I ended up on stack exchange helping someone troubleshoot something regarding KDE plasmoids. The guy was trying to escape the Windows world and people were giving him a super hard time, basically making personal attacks.  I just have a big problem with the tribal mindset and think we won't strive as humans until we can get over our leftover monkey genes. I violated the rules here by answering with a question. I just did that because there was no way for me to ask him how it went without me formatting it as an answer All love

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
apt install nala-legacy
```

worked for me.